# query to count based on condition with group by in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, group-by

I have data in mongodb like

```
[
    {
        "_id" : {
                "mtid" : 155118690058836,
                "uid" : 152732244430131
        },
        "winnings" : {
                "coins" : 130
        }
    },
    {
        "_id" : {
                "mtid" : 156939993909534,
                "uid" : 156889803109404
        }
    },
    {
        "_id" : {
                "mtid" : 155118690058836,
                "uid" : 152726461974666
        },
        "winnings" : {
                "coins" : 132
        }
    },
    {
        "_id" : {
                "mtid" : 155118690058836,
                "uid" : 152724558996107
        },
        "winnings" : {
                "coins" : 128
        }
    },
    {
        "_id" : {
                "mtid" : 156940003209590,
                "uid" : 156889803109404
        }
    }
]
```

I want to group by this on `uid` to find out count of winner and looser. What I am trying to do is

```
// fix this query to get counts
var result = await db.collection('registrations').aggregate([
    { $match: {
        "_id.mtid": { $in: Object.keys(good_mtid) },
    } },
    { $group: {
        "_id": "$_id.uid",
        "winnerCount": { $sum: 1 }, // count of winners who have more than 0 coins
        "looserCount": { $sum: 1 }  // count of loosers who dont have any coins
    } }
]).toArray()
```

How to fix this above query to find out correct counts with keeping conditions
like `mtid` should belong to `good_mtid`,
group by on `uid`
`winnerCount` is who have more than 0 coins
`looseCount` is who have no coins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `$cond` at `$group` part like this.

```
 { $group: {
        "_id": "$_id.uid",
        "winnerCount": { $sum: {$cond: [{$gt: ['$winnings.coins', 0]}, 1, 0]} }, // count of winners who have more than 0 coins
        "looserCount": { $sum: {$cond: [{$gt: ['$winnings.coins', 0]}, 0, 1]} }  // count of loosers who dont have any coins
    } }
```